# How to hook up springboot to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying build a rest api using springboot and mongo db. I have a local MongoDB installed and running, and I tried to hook up the springboot to use it. However rest api kept return empty list even though I have tons of data in Mongo. I also tried adding some test data using the rest api, it succeeded but i don't see it in MongoDB. just wondering which mongo it uses? my database is `my-store`, collection name is `processes`.

In my `application.properties` file, I specified the MongoDB database to the one I'm using:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=my-store
```

And here is my java code:

repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "processes", path="processes")
public interface ProcessRepository extends MongoRepository<Process, String> {
    public List<Process> findAll();
}
```

controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/processes")
public class ProcessRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Process> getAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
    ...
    }
```

Finally figured out what's wrong, the collection name is 'processes' but the java model is 'Process', there are two ways to fix it:
1. rename the java model object to 'Proecesses'
2. keep the java model object 'Process', but added annotation as below:

```
@Document(collection="processes")  <=== annotation here
public class Process {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String message;
    private Long highWatermark;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation recently. The collections was named "Person", and the class was also named "Person". The java program always returned an empty list. It was noted that a collection created by code, from the java program had a name starting with lower case. Taking this into consideration I created a collection with name "person" (small case) and the program returned the complete list. Hope this helps beginners in mongoDB